# what is the best way of removing start and end slashes in a string -if exist- and keep the middle ones using TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have these variations of strings:

```
some/dir/with/end/slash/
/some/dir/with/start/slash
some/dir/without/any/start/or/end/slash
/some/dir/with/both/slashes/
```

What I want is, in single context, I want to remove start end end slashes IF exist and leave if it doesn't and keep the middle ones.

How can I make it in **one go**?

I am using NodeJS+TypeScript.

Expected result:

```
some/dir/with/end/slash
some/dir/with/start/slash
some/dir/without/any/start/or/end/slash
some/dir/with/both/slashes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use replace method with the following pattern

```
`^\/|\/$`
```

- `^` - Anchor to start of string
- `\/` - Matches `/`
- `$` - End of string

```js
let arr = [`some/dir/with/end/slash/`,`/some/dir/with/start/slash`,`some/dir/without/any/start/or/end/slash`,`/some/dir/with/both/slashes/`]

arr.forEach(e=>{
  let str = e.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')
  console.log(str)
})
```

**Alternates**

1. using smple for loop

```js
let arr = [`some/dir/with/end/slash/`,`/some/dir/with/start/slash`,`some/dir/without/any/start/or/end/slash`,`/some/dir/with/both/slashes/`]

arr.forEach(e=>{
  let str = ''
  for(let i=0; i<e.length; i++){
    if(( i === 0 || i === e.length-1 ) && e[i] ==='/'){
      continue
    } else {
      str += e[i]
    }
   }
  console.log(str)
})
```

2. using startsWith and endsWith

```js
let arr = [`some/dir/with/end/slash/`,`/some/dir/with/start/slash`,`some/dir/without/any/start/or/end/slash`,`/some/dir/with/both/slashes/`]

arr.forEach(e=>{
  let str = e
  if(e.startsWith('/')){
    str = str.substring(1,)
  }
  if(e.endsWith('/')){
    str = str.substring(0,str.length-1)
  }
  console.log(str)
})
```